# D3 line graph red line for zero values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 to render a basic line chart which is working fine.

The problem is that I want to paint a red line when the value is `0`, however it does not quite work as expected. Here is an example of what I am talking about (notice the blue line **and** the red line - the red line should stop when the values are not `0`. You can ignore the vertical lines):

[image]

Here is the code I am using to render the lines:

This renders the  blue line:

```
svg
  .append('svg:path')
  .attr('class', 'line' + i)
  .attr('d', () => lineGen(d.values))
  .attr('stroke', () => d.values[0].color)
  .attr('stroke-width', 4)
  .attr('fill', 'none');
```

And this renders the red line:

```
svg
  .append('svg:path')
  .attr('class', 'line' + i)
  .attr('d', () => lineGen(d.values.filter((item: any) => item.value === 0)))
  .attr('stroke', '#ff0053')
  .attr('stroke-width', 4)
  .attr('fill', 'none');
```

And the `lineGen` function:

```
const lineGen: Line<[number, number]> = d3
  .line()
  .x(d => xScale(d[objX]))
  .y(d => yScale(d[objY]));
```

**How can I prevent red line from being drawn when the values are not zero?**

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for this ?